# Ratio Test Series Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose I have a sequence $a_n$ which I know is monotone decreasing and converges to $0$. The series $\sum{a_n}$ also converges. I am trying to show that the limit of the subsequences   $$\lim_{k\to \infty}|\frac{a_{2^{k+1}}}{a_{2^k}}|$$ converges to a value of less than $\frac{1}{2}$. Intuitively, since it is monotone decreasing I know that after a certain value of $k$, the values of the top sequence will be smaller than that of the bottom sequence, and therefore this should be less than $1$. But I am having trouble showing this. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the sequence necessarily converges, but there is something you can say. By the [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum 2^n a_{2^n}$ converges. Now we have

$$\frac{2^{n+1}a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^n a_{2^n}} = 2 \frac{a_{2^{n+1}}}{a_{2^n}}$$

Since the second series converges, then it follows from the ratio test that the series will diverge if

$$ \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{2^{n+1}}}{a_{2^n}} > 1/2 $$

Answer (score 0):

Take as sequence for the changed requirement the one with value
$$
a_n=\frac1{8^{k+1}}\qquad\text{for } 4^k< n\le 4^{k+1}
$$
or
$$
a_n=8^{-\left\lceil \frac{\log_2 n}2\right\rceil}
$$
Then the series converges, and the given ratio will alternatingly take the value $1$.